# Python recursion on _getattr_ in my class decorator

Tags: python, recursion, getattr

I write a function (Python 3.x) for use it as a class decorator than make attributes private or public.
First of all I wrote my 'private' function:

```
def private(attrlist):
    def wrapper(obj):
        class fPrivate:
            def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
                self.__wrapped = obj(*args,**kwargs)
            def __getattr__(self,args):
                if attrlist(args):
                    raise TypeError('Get on a provate attr')
                else:
                    return getattr(self.__wrapped,args)
            def __setattr__(self,args,val):
                if args == '_fPrivate.__wrapped':
                    self.__dict__[args] = val
                elif attrlist(args):
                    raise TypeError('Set on private')
                else:
                    setattr(self.__wrapped,args,val)
        return fPrivate
    return wrapper
```

then I use two different methods to declare Private and Pubblic method, like this:

```
def setPriv(*lists):
    return private(attrlist=(lambda args: args in lists))
def setPub(*lists):
    return private(attrlist=(lambda args: args not in lists))
```

at this point I test my work:

```
@setPriv('name')
class t1:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

But when I create my first instance

```
a = t1('Bob',40)
```

I got this error:

```
> File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 11, in __getattr__
getattr(self.__wrapped,args)
File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 11, in __getattr__
getattr(self.__wrapped,args)
File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 11, in __getattr__
getattr(self.__wrapped,args)
File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 11, in __getattr__
getattr(self.__wrapped,args)
File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 8, in __getattr__
if attrlist(args):
File "C:\Code\utils\private.py", line 25, in <lambda>
return private(attrlist=(lambda args: args in lists))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `getattr` results in `__getattr__` being called.

Comment: @Vallentin Not necessarily. `__getattribute__` is called first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the name of an attribute has been *mangled*, the rules for naming in Python are still obeyed, so attribute `__wrapped` will read `_fPrivate__wrapped` not `_fPrivate.__wrapped`; without dot(s).

If you check your traceback, you'll see the error is raised in the `__init__` when you first try to set `self.__wrapped`, which is turn calls `__getattribute__` and then `__getattr__`, and since `__getattr__` again contains an attribute access viz. `self.__wrapped`, it goes on and on.

Removing that dot ensures, `_fPrivate__wrapped` makes it to the instance dictionary and setting the attribute calls `__getattribute__` which returns the attribute cleanly and has no need to search deeper.

```
a = t1('Bob',40)

a.age = 7
print(a.age)
# 7
a.name = 'me'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 38, in <module>
  File "python", line 15, in __setattr__
TypeError: Set on private
```